# Wicked PDF does not showing webp format images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm using this tag but it does not support webp format file it does not show image on pdf for webp format. images for other formats it is working fine

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag(my_img, height: '300')  %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wicked PDF is a wrapper around `wkhtmltopdf`. And currents stable version of `wkhtmltopdf` doesn't support webp: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3977

If webp support is important for you, you should be looking for other gems. But I think, will be easier to store converted image in png/jpeg format specially for pdf.